# Just starting to learn Guitar (thinking of buying a Yamaha silent electro as a practice guitar - Maybe!)

Tags: practice

Good evening everyone,

As the title says, I'm just starting out on the journey to learn guitar, and whilst I have around maybe 6/8 hours a week I can commit to doing this, I'm at that time shortly after separating from the wife, growing bored, and sick of moping, so I jumped in.

Anyhow. My question is to do with practicing, and noise thereof.

I was thinking of buying a Yamaha silent electro-acoustic as a back up to practice banging out cords in the evening/nights without upsetting the household, I have the kids!

With this in mind, should I invest circa 700 quid and go for a full blown version, or should I, as a friend suggested, normally he's full of not so useful crap, and just buy an eight string silent Ukulele which are around 500 pounds cheaper.

Personally, I think he was taking the *iss, but then again he could have a point, and the advice online is pretty sketchy to say the least.

In the absence of a yes on either, does anyone have any decent suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any advice and assistance you can offer.

JJ

Comment: Why not just get an electric and play through headphones or unplugged at night?

Comment: Although this site doesn't make equipment recommendations, you might find some helpful information here: [How do you identify a good acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/how-do-you-identify-a-good-acoustic-guitar). It's a bit tangential to your question, but might provide some helpful insights.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think of the 100% electric option! The guitar I bought was a nice spanking new carbon Lava Roundback, I thought if I spent some money on it it'll be a good motivator, but I do see your point. I'm sure to be back as I can think of a few other questions I have, but as with all things, one step, or chord, at a time! Thanks......